# How to know what indexes are being used in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, explain, database-indexes

I have a table in my MYSQL database with many indexes created, but I don't know what of these indexes are useful and what are not. I'd like to know what are the indexes being used in production.

Is there any way to have a log of indexes used?

I know the EXPLAIN command, but this is for one specific query. I have a complex system, so I can't know exactly what are the queries being used. I could turn the general log, get all the queries and make an EXPLAIN for all of them, and then get the aggregated result, but there must have to be a easier way to do this.

Comment: Do you know this tool? http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/11/11/advanced-index-analysis-with-mk-index-usage/ . Although it uses a similar attempt then yours -> post analysis, not live analysis

Comment: Just a heads up: Since that article, maatkit was renamed to percona-toolkit, and this tool is now `pt-index-usage`.

Answer (score 0):

For analyzing queries and indexes, I use GUI tool called [SQLYog](http://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog). Ver useful, powerful and easy to use.